# GXT 3 MultiSort Grid

Tags: java, gwt, grid, gxt

How can I get multiple sort a Grid in GXT 3?
And how is the best way to view this to the user? Maybe in a Toolbar.

I have For multiple Filter i can you use a FilterPagingLoadConfig, but what for multiple Sort

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try to add more than 1 StoreSortInfo in your Grid List Store, i.e.:

```
listStore.addSortInfo(new StoreSortInfo<YourModelDataClass>(propertiesModel.firstSortCriteria(), SortDir.ASC));
listStore.addSortInfo(new StoreSortInfo<YourModelDataClass>(propertiesModel.secondSortCriteria(), SortDir.DESC));
listStore.addSortInfo(new StoreSortInfo<YourModelDataClass>(propertiesModel.thirdSortCriteria(), SortDir.ASC));
```

For the best way to present your sort criteria to user, you can use toolbar, and add some checkbox as much as your criteria, each time user check / uncheck it, just arrange your list store sort.